# Borel–Weil–Bott for partial flag varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Is there a generalization of Borel-Weil-Bott for partial flag varieties, i.e. homogeneous spaces of the form $G/P$ with $P$ parabolic and $G$ semisimple? If so, I would like a reference.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the usual Borel-Weil-Bott by noting that the (derived) pushforward from $G/B$ to $G/P$ of a line bundle pulled back from $G/P$ is again that line bundle?

Comment: @WillSawin How does that help?

Comment: The cohomology of any equivariant line bundle on $G/P$ is equal to the cohomology of its pullback to $G/B$, which can be calculated using the usual Borel-Weil-Bott, by the Leray spectral sequence.

Comment: Section 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2575 and references therein should be useful.

Comment: @Jef's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376067/borel-weil-bott-for-partial-flag-varieties#comment953516_376067):  [Gruson, Sam, and Weyman - Moduli of Abelian varieties, Vinberg theta-groups, and free resolutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2575).

Comment: @WillSawin Ok, I see why that answers my question. However, it’s not immediately clear to me why the natural map from a line bundle on $G/P$ to its pull-then-push is an isomorphism rather than just injective. (Though injectivity is enough to give me what I want)

Comment: @AviSteiner Because the fibers are connected (and have no coherent cohomology, if you're interested in the derived pushforward). This is a local question, so we can work locally on $G/P$, and in particular assume the line bundle is trivial - it's a question about $f_* \mathcal O_{G/B}$. We know this is trivial for a proper separable map with reduced connected fibers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many places that give a complete  answer to your question: One is a paper in the Annals of Math written by Kostant around the middle fifties, other more geometrical is due to Griffits-Schmid published in Acta Mathematica in the late sixties.
best regards